# How do I preserve a UNIX socket across reboots (RasPi, Arch, chroot)

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, nginx

I've set up nginx and php-fpm under Arch Linux on a RasPi. nginx was set up in a chroot as described in the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/nginx#Installation_in_a_chroot). Everything runs fine when `php-fpm.conf` and `nginx.conf` are set up to listen to `127.0.0.1:9000` and `php-fpm.conf` doesn't declare a path to the pid.

Now I want to change the setup to use a UNIX socket as is suggested across the web. So I added to `php-fpm.conf` the following.

```
pid = /srv/http/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
...
[www]
chroot = /srv/http;
listen = /srv/http/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

Also replaced `fastcgi_pass` in `nginx.conf` with

```
fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
```

When I manually create the `.sock` file and restart both php-fpm and nginx, it works. But whenever I reboot, the `php-fpm` directory and `.sock` file are gone...

How can I preserve them across reboots? `/etc/fstab` includes

```
tmpfs           /srv/http/run   tmpfs   rw,noexec,relatime,size=1024k   0       0
tmpfs           /srv/http/tmp   tmpfs   rw,noexec,relatime,size=102400k 0       0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  This would be the same thing as preserving a TCP connection over reboot.  The socket is created by the process that listens on it (in your case `php-fpm`) and `nginx` connects to it.  If you get problems because `nginx` can't open it, you most probably start your services in the wrong order (you'd have to start `php-fpm` before starting `nginx`, so that the socket exists when `nginx` starts).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Also shows I need to learn a lot more about networking :). I'll look into the starting order of processes in `systemctl`.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. Starting `php-fpm.service` before `nginx.service` simply results in `nginx` not starting at all, as `php-fpm` won't start because the sock file doesn't exist... I'll start a new question, as the issue seems to be to let `php-fpm.service` create the sock at startup.

Answer (score 0):

tmpfiles (part of systemd) will create and remove temporary/volatile directories and files. Typically these are placed in /run or /tmp, but it will work anywhere.

To have the directory /srv/http/run/php-fpm create on startup, create a config file in **/etc/tmpfiles.d** like this:

```
d /srv/http/run/php-fpm 0755 http http -
```

This will create the directory with the permissions 0755 for the http user and group (Arch's default php-fpm / web user)

The file can be called whatever you like but needs to end in .conf. Example (**php-fpm.conf**)

The socket itself is created by php-fpm when it starts, so be sure it is enabled in systemd:

```
systemctl enable php-fpm
```